# Big XML - copy data from nth Occurrences to another file

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, wc

```
<XML>
<Employee>
<firstname></firstname><lastname></lastname>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<firstname></firstname><lastname></lastname>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<firstname></firstname><lastname></lastname>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<firstname></firstname><lastname></lastname>
</Employee>
<company>
<companyname></companyname><address></address>
</company>
<XML>
```

We have a very big XML file with above patterns containing around 40k records, We wanted to copy data to another from 20k  occurrence to 30k th  occurrence
Kindly help us the same, the `wc -l` showing only 50 lines. But the number of records has more than 40k.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an XML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet, ...).

Comment: If you have an example can you pls provide me it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean under *occurence*: 1 record e.g. `<firstname></firstname>` ; 1 block `<Employee></Employee>` ; 1 block of company… ?

Comment: Please improve your question. It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to write some script/small program that employs XML parser. Then you can count records as they getting parsed and filter out only the stuff you need.

Comment: Actually I am not unix programer, If some one will help in this it will be gr8 help.

Comment: Likely you will need to learn some programming language.

Comment: I can suggest to attempy Python. And here is example how to work with XML http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_xml_processing.htm